# ANR in sqliteopenhelper?

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite

I have an android project includes some services, alarms and broadcastreceivers and also activities of course and all of them can access sqlite. I know that android environment gives us only one sqlite connection to process and because of that i had to implement singleton design pattern on my project to use SqliteOpenHelper. However, when count of services and receivers increase, some concurrency related errors arised so i chose to use isDbLockedByCurrentThread method in my getter method. Unfortunately, this caused anr problems. What's the best behaviour to use sqlite in android app with concurrent writeable access?

Here is my dbhelper class:

https://gist.github.com/sedatsevgili/2422c9003336419fb366

Comment: You should use multiconnection. Create pool and get connection destroy connection mechanism.(Same as Consumer, worker group)